# Convert Spanish characters to unicode with PHP

Tags: php, json, unicode

When I use json_encode to encode Spanish characters it changes them from this:

```
áéíóú¿¡üñ
```

To this:

```
\u00e1\u00e9\u00ed\u00f3\u00fa\u00bf\u00a1\u00fc\u00f1
```

When I use this code:

```
$str = array();
$str[] = 'áéíóú¿¡üñ';
$str[] = 'áéíóú¿¡üñ';
$json_data = json_encode( $str );
```

My question is how can I convert the characters to this format before I use json_encode? How can I convert the characters to I think unicode(?) format as shown without using json_encode?

Comment: try json_encode($str,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear - I want to encode Spanish characters into unicode without using json_encode - I think there must be a PHP function which does this but I can't find it

Comment: If you want universal character support, the simplest thing really is to use `json_encode`: `substr(json_encode($str), 1, -1)`. Otherwise you'll need to define what to do with characters outside the BMP; JSON already defines it…

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by converting the string to `UTF-8` with:

```
iconv()
```

and then converting the `UTF-8` string to hexidecimal with:

```
bin2hex()
```

After conversion, you will need to manipulate the order of the encoding of each character - here is an example below:

```
<?php
$spanishCharacterString = 'áéíóú¿¡üñ';

/* Convert the string to UTF-8 and then into hexadecimal */
$encodedSpanishCharacterString = bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2', $spanishCharacterString));

/* Break string into individual characters */
$spanishCharacterArray = str_split($encodedSpanishCharacterString, 4);

/* Format the encoding of each character */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($spanishCharacterArray); $i++) {
    $spanishCharacterArray[$i] = '\u'.substr($spanishCharacterArray[$i], -2, 2).substr($spanishCharacterArray[$i], 0, 2);
}

/* Join the encoded characters back up again */
$convertedSpanishCharacterString = implode($spanishCharacterArray);

echo $convertedSpanishCharacterString;

?>
```

Comment: Note that this ain't gonna work for characters above the BMP, like emoji.

Comment: Which emojis are "Spanish characters"? ;-)

Comment: Quite obviously: 